# JavaScript sweetAlert popup closes itself after a quick second

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have a SweetAlert popup, but it is closing itself automatically. Normally it should stay until user clicks 'OK'. (I have included and tested all SweetAlert files.)

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

---

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    swal("Submitted!", "Your Issue has been submitted!", "success");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? If that's a submit button, is your page changing before the alert can complete?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like it's a form submit, So when you click the button the page refreshes.That's why you see the alert for a second and it hides.

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

You must change the button type to be `button`.

```
   <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Just to append: even if you change the type of the button, you'll need to remove the button from  inside the <form> tag if it's inside

Comment: Thanks a lot this saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Note that if your button is part of a form submit, then [issue 284](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/284) suggests it's not currently supported.  You can change your button to a regular button (rather than a submit button) and programmatically submit the form from the callback in a sweetalert callback.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem..
when click outside of the popup, the popup window closes automatically and change the page very fast...

I tried this code for stop close sweetalert itself, and refresh the page when the user click "OK" of sweetalert window.

HTML:

```
<form  method="post" action="contact.php" name="myform" onsubmit="return myFunction()">

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="full" placeholder="* Full Name" required="" >

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="last" placeholder="* Last Name" required="">

<input type="submit" value="send" name="sends" class="btn btn-lg">

</form>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var full=document.myform.full.value;
  var last=document.myform.last.value;
  if (full==null || last==null){
    swal("Error...!!!!!!");
    return false;
}else{
    swal("Congrats!", ", Your account is created!", "success");
    return true;}
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you don't use redirect in form (to page "contact.php"), you should change your submit function to: ```onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return myFunction();"```, and make ajax request to page instead. Else you will be redirected