# Sweetalert closes suddenly after appearing because of page reload

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I'm using javascript sweetalert dialog. The dialog closes after appearing because of page reload. I have applied the suggested fixes in answer to the [Question-javascript-sweetalert-popup-closes-itself-after-a-quick-second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348785/javascript-sweetalert-popup-closes-itself-after-a-quick-second)

My template code is

```
<button title="Transform" id="transform_btn" type="button" class="btn" style="color:white;background-color:#fff;">
 <a href="/load_to_hive/{{stu.cases_id}}/">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass fa-2x"></i>
 </a>
</button>
```

And javascript code displaying the dialog is

```
{% block javascript %}
<script src="{% static 'js/sweetalert.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
var transformBtn= document.getElementById('transform_btn');
transformBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
swal({
  title: "Good job!",
  text: "You clicked the button!",
  icon: "success",
});
})
</script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

**Edit**
I'm trying to show the alert with some delay i.e., the page has reloaded but it's not working. I don't know why:

```
<script>
var transformBtn= document.getElementById('transform_btn');
  transformBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    swal({
      title: "Good job!",
      text: "You clicked the button!",
      icon: "success",
    })
    },3000);
  })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a link inside your button. The problem here is most likely that your page is navigating to the new page as soon as you click the button.

As a side note, I can't think of any circumstance where you should have an anchor tag inside a button like that. Either just have an anchor tag, and then style it so that it looks like a button, or just have a button. But definitely not both.

There's a few ways you could fix this, and the best one will depend on what it is you want to happen. but if you want to navigate to a new page after clicking the button, I would just make the confirm button of your sweet alerts pop-up a link. Something like this:

```
swal({
  title: "Good job!",
  text: "You clicked the button!",
  confirmButtonText: '<a href="/load_to_hive/{{stu.cases_id}}/">',
  icon: "success",
});
```

Other ways would be to await till the user has clicked success and use javascript to navigate. It really depends on what you want the button to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Put   befor swal event.preventDefault() 

$( "form#measure-the-heat").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the page from redirecting

  // Put the swal-code here
});
```